# Empty Pages after section or figures

Tags: tables, blank-page

i got several tables/figures and sections like this:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{...}\label{sec:...}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{table}[H]
    \renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3mm}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            ...
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{...}
        \label{...}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

After e.g. this definition I got a complete blank page within my PDF. I think it is something about the `[H]` parameter but i am not able to fix it, because without `[H]` the table does not appear below the section headline.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I didn't get a blank page when I replaced "H" by "h"!

Comment: @AlexTape, `H` is not good selection for `table` positioning. If the table is to big to be fitted in the page, where is it would appear, all table with following text is move to the next page and left emty space in the previous page as you observed.

Comment: The reason latex (and typesetting systems generally) move floats is to avoid white space at page breaks. So `[H]` which is only there to prevent floats being moved, _by design_ is likely to introduce ugly white space at page breaks.

Comment: Also, \begin{center}..\end{center} wastes additional space (compared to \centering).

Comment: Just how big is this table?  If it is too big it will be forced onto a page of floats.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: the size varies from 2-3 lines to a half page.. the issue appearing by the bigger ones.. furthermore i got the same issue for half-page figures.. i dunno how to position figures/tables well with [H] or [h] or whatever..

Comment: Please give us some compilable code and not just a snippet. What about using `\centering` and using `h` instead of `H`?